# RadioListTile onchange value is object? type

Tags: flutter, casting, radio-button, dart-null-safety

I am trying to make multiple choice questions using `RadioListTile`.

```dart
RadioListTile(
  value: 1,
  groupValue: 1,
  onChanged: (val) {
    print("Value");
    print(val.runtimeType);
    setSelectedRadio(val);
  },
  title: Text(snapshot.data!.data()["questions"]["question $i"]["option 1"]),
);
```

The error I am getting is

> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'. 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.       setSelectedRadio(val);

I have checked the runtime type of value and it is returning int.

Comment: In which line you are getting this error?

Comment: Object' is from 'dart:core'.
setSelectedRadio(val); in val

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `int` as a generic argument to your `RadioListTile`.

Replace this

```dart
RadioListTile(...)
```

with this

```dart
RadioListTile<int>(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the issue by either specifying a type to your `RadioListTile` or explicitly specifying the function argument type.

##### Option 1:

```
RadioListTile<int>(
   // Remaining Code
)
```

##### Option 2:

```
RadioListTile(
   onChanged: (int? val) {},

   // Remaining Code                      
)
```